PN532 Library Synchronization with Android Application Failed
This question is a related to my previous question. I have made a CMakeList.txt and also native-lib.cpp and upload it in my Android application
to synchronize the nfclib for android that was downloaded from the github
Here is my CMakeList.txt:
# Minimum version of CMake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

# Project name
project(nfc_app)

# Specify the library to be built as a shared library
add_library(
        # Name of the library to be built (native JNI library)
        nfc_native_lib  # This should be a logical name for the library

        # Build as a shared library
        SHARED

        # Add your native source files here
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp  # Ensure this is the correct path
)

# Set the path to the libnfc header files (should point to headers, not .so)
include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/libnfc.so/libnfc/pn532.h  # Path to libnfc headers (.h files)
)

# Find the libnfc library
find_library(
        libnfc-lib  # Variable to store the result of the find
        nfc         # Name of the library (libnfc.so is what will be searched)
        PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a  # Path where .so file is located
)

# Set path to additional libraries if required (for example, if libnfc is in a custom directory)
# You can adjust this path as per your project structure
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a)

# Link the native library with libnfc and any other necessary libraries (e.g., log for logging)
target_link_libraries(
        nfc_native_lib       # The JNI library you're building (same name as in add_library)
        ${libnfc-lib}         # Link libnfc (found using find_library)
        log                   # Optional: Android NDK logging library
)

and here is my native-lib.cpp:
#include <jni.h>
#include <nfc/nfc.h>  // Include libnfc headers

JNIEXPORT jstring  extern "C" JNICALL
Java_com_example_nfc_app_MainActivity_readNFC(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) 
    // Use libnfc functions here
    nfc_device *device = NULL;  // Declare the NFC device pointe

    // Initialize libnfc, interact with the NFC reader (PN532), etc.
    nfc_context *context;
    nfc_init(&context);

    if (context == NULL) {
        return env->NewStringUTF("Failed to initialize libnfc");
    }

    // Open the NFC device
    device = nfc_open(context, NULL);  // NULL means using the first available device
    if (device == NULL) {
        nfc_exit(context);
        return env->NewStringUTF("Failed to open NFC device");
   }

but, still an error pops out while syncing the gradle files with the project:
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.


"the following variables" being...?

regarding your CMake file: You cannot hardcode architectures like that. Every instance of "arm64-v8a" or "armeabi-v7a" must be replaced by ${ANDROID_ABI} since the Android build system will invoke your CMake build system separately for every ABI you chose in your build.gradle(.kts). Instead of find_library you should instead create an IMPORTED library and set its IMPORTED_LOCATION and INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES properties.

alright. thank you for the pointing that out. I might think that nfc library attached with this application is set to NOTFOUND because everytime I am building this project, the error shows the same which is no source given to target: native-lib.cpp

Your path should be relative to the Cmakelists.txt file, so drop the src/main/cpp/ part. Likewise, your CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR is src/main/cpp from the project root, so if you want to reference files in jniLibs you need to go UP the tree.
